# Rofi does not launch certain programs in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: launcher, htop

I use Rofi as my application launcher. However, when I try to launch certain applications like anaconda-navigator, spyder I get the following error message:

> Failed to execute: 'spyder'
> Error: 'Failed to execute child process "spyder" (No such file of directory)'

However, I have no issues launching these apps from the terminal(alacritty).

Rofi does not even launch htop, although it gives no error message regarding htop.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

**EDIT: Ubuntu Version: 20.04.1**
| Window Manger: SPECTRWM

Update: Rofi is able to launch anaconda-navigator and spyder but not htop when I launch rofi from the terminal using the command:

> rofi -show run

However when I launch rofi using the keybinding, super+shift+p, it is unable to launch the programs.

**EDIT 2: Problem solved by adding $PATH to ~/.profile**

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Where are `anaconda-navigator`, `spyder` and `htop`? (`type -p anaconda-navigator`). Are these directories in. the `$PATH` when you launch `Rofi`?

Comment: locations for anaconda-navigator, spyder and htop are in the $PATH. I can launch these applications from the terminal but not from rofi.

Comment: A process inherits its `$PATH` (and other environment variables) from its parent, at the time of process creation. Use full paths for the commands, look at `env | sort` both under `rofi` and the terminal. Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding $PATH to ~/.profile. SPECTRWM does not use the $PATH from bashrc but from ~/.profile.